# Why cant put my data into an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have about 20 tables in my db,  im running query inside a while loop to get all that table data and store data of each table inside an array, looping and everything happens fine but storing part does not happen. can any body help me to store data of each table inside an array

code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){
$table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];


         $excute = mysql_query("
         SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
         FROM    $table a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID
         WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
         GROUP BY ID;") or die(mysql_error());
         $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
         $tables = array();
         $tables .= $result;
}
print_r($tables);
```

Comment: what do those commas do in your SQL query? I mean the `",table_1,"` part.  It doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Use `$tables = $row["TABLE_NAME"];` instead of **$table=** and it should be fine.

Comment: i dont what ur trying to say

Comment: Also please do not use `mysql_*` since the this extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO_MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is little mistake in your syntax in foreach use this

```
foreach ($table as $tables) {
```

Correct syntax of forech is

```
foreach(array_expression as $variable)
{

}
```

Update====

```
$tables = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count))
{
    $table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

    $excute = mysql_query("
    SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
    FROM    $table a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID
    WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
    GROUP BY ID;") or die(mysql_error());

    while($finalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute))
    {
        $tables[$i][] = $finalRes;
    }
    $i++;   
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tables);
```

And you are using this wrongly.

Comment: for each is not necessary... so i removed it,... all i want is to add elements to the array

Comment: works like a charm bro.. but small problem.. each table is not separated, all data comes in one array.. is there any way to get it separated for each table... i mean index wise

Comment: $table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'milepostdb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%' ");